# How do I wire a new ceiling light from an existing fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

How do I extend electrical service to a new basement ceiling light fixture? I want to extend from a standard ceiling light that is wired as follows: two 14/3 gauge wires enter the box. Both black wires are spliced together. Each red wire is attached to the brass lamp holder screws and each white wires are attached to the silver lamp holder screws. How do I connect my new 14/2 gauge wire from this lamp holder to the new ceiling lamp holder?

Comment: Is the existing light controlled by a single switch, or is it controlled by 2 switches (3-way)?  
You say both black wires are spliced together - are they attached to the lamp at all, then? A picture might help here, because the use of the red wire in a standard single-switch lamp seems out of place. 
Basically, you need black and white wires to run from your currently lamp to the new one. But lets ensure you have standard wire colors first.

Comment: How many fixtures are controlled by the switch?

Comment: And is the new light to be controlled by this existing switch or switches, or does the new light need to have its own switch?

Comment: When was the original wiring competed? Recent code changes require a grounded (neutral) conductor at all switches, so 14/3 cable is becoming more common.